# Case condition not working for ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

Tags: oracle, case

I have a logic where doing some calculation like below is giving error as

> ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

I have added `CASE` condition like below

`V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR := (case when v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT <> then to_char((POWER(1 + (v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT * 2.5/ 100 / v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT), v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT) - 1) * 100, '99990D99' end) as`

Where am I going wrong?

Full code is below:

```
v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT := floor((months_between(to_date(V_BILLSTART_DT), to_date(V_FINALSRDATE, 'dd-mm-yy'))) /12);
V_AMTINMONTH := CAST(to_char(LAST_DAY(V_DATEVARIABLE),'dd') AS INT); 
V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR := (case when v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT <> then to_char((POWER(1 + 
 (v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT * 2.5/ 100 / v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT), v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT) - 1) * 100, 
'99990D99' end) as
 V_APP_FAIR_RENT := (v_FAIR_RENT_AMT * V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR) / 100 + v_FAIR_RENT_AMT;
V_APP_FAIR_RENT := V_APP_FAIR_RENT / V_AMTINMONTH;
V_APP_FAIR_RENT := ROUND(V_APP_FAIR_RENT * V_NOOFDAYSINMONTH);
```

Comment: Apart from the current error, this `case when v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT <> then` is already a typo

Comment: oh I missed it, but `Error(429,184): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     ) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset `

Comment: The error should stem from the fact when denominator(v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT or V_AMTINMONTH ) is equal to zero, where we don't know those column values.

Comment: can u provide the solution for this ?

Comment: The solution is not obvious without knowing those columns' values.

Comment: CASE needs ELSE.  If your condition is not met the ELSE supplies the default value.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: those columns values are integer values for ex: 1, 2, 3 like this

Comment: @Stilgar: can u please provide those part ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: please suggest something so that I can close this issue

Comment: **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a date.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR := (case when v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT <> then to_char((POWER(1 + 
 (v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT * 2.5/ 100 / v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT), v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT) - 1) * 100, 
'99990D99' end) as
```

Has multiple errors.

- `case when v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT <> then` is invalid syntax as there is nothing on the right-hand side of the `<>` operator.
- The statement ends with `as` and not a `;` statement terminator.
- In `v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT * 2.5/ 100 / v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT` you can cancel out the `v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT` terms and simplify the entire statement to just `0.025`

You have other errors including:

- Using `TO_DATE` on `V_BILLSTART_DT` and `V_FINALSRDATE` which, although you have not given the data type, are presumably `DATE` data types and you should **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on values that are already dates.
- `months_between(date1, date2)` subtracts `date2` from `date1` and not the other way round. I'm assuming you want to subtract the start date from the final date and end up with a positive value; not subtract the final date from the start date and end up with a negative value.

You probably want something like:

```sql
DECLARE
  V_BILLSTART_DT DATE := DATE '2022-01-01';
  V_FINALSRDATE  DATE := DATE '2022-12-31';
  v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT NUMBER;
  V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT := floor(months_between(V_FINALSRDATE, V_BILLSTART_DT)/12);
  V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR  := to_char(
                            (POWER(1.025, v_YEARMSAFORAPPRENT) - 1) * 100, 
                            'fm99990D00'
                          );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_EFFEC_PER_APPFAIR);
END;
/
```

*Note: I've ignored the other lines as they did not appear to be relevant to your stated error message; there may be more errors in those ignored lines but you'll have to debug them yourself.*